# Free GIT Client which support pull requests management

Tags: windows, gratis, git

I have created my own git server with individual user accounts which is publicly accessible. Now i want my team members to access it and create branch and generate pull request etc. Till now everything is fine. Team members can create branch and merge branch using the tool like GITHUB Desktop. Now the issue is we are trying to find a tool which can support pool request.

Is there any free GIT client for windows which can provide all below features:

1. Generate Pull Request against any branch user wants
2. View Pull Request
3. Add any feedback/comment for given pull request
4. Approve pull request so it can get merge with requested branch

Note: We can't use GITHUB, BitBucket because of pricing issue.

Comment: Pull request aren't a feature of Git, they're a proprietary feature of GitHub, so Git in itself doesn't even knows what they are. Look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9630774/2557263) for an alternative on the same problem.

Comment: Is there any client software which supports git request-pull @Alejandro

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you asked for, but if you are fine with hosting a service somewhere:

[Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab) is basically the open-source version of github which you can host yourself.

[Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) is a tool for code reviews, and as such supports a pull request workflow.

Client-side I actually did find a client that supports (creating) pull requests with git request-pull:

[Tortoise git](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-patch.html#tgit-dug-patch-pullrequest) supports git request-pull. It's basically just a GUI for you to input the parameters to the command, though.